# Arbitary plane curve.

Tags: geometry

Does an arbitrary curve in the plane necessarily pass through a rational point? That is, a point of the form $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers.

Comment: line $y=x+ \pi$

Comment: Some don't; the rest almost never do.  (In $ \ \mathbb{R}^n \ $ , "almost nothing" is a rational point.)

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by *arbitrary* and by *curve*. For example, are you considering algebraic, smooth, or continuous (or maybe some other kind of) curves? And by arbitrary do you mean every curve or do you mean "almost every" curve (in some sense to be specified)?

Comment: Every continuous non constant function from an interval into $R^2$

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to put a topology or a measure on $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\Bbb{R}^2)$ (which are the only two ways I know of that give a precise meaning to the term *arbitrary*), but I would guess that by most standards almost all those functions don't have a rational point, as they can be quite ill-behaved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $\{(\sqrt{2},y):y\in\Bbb R\}$ is a line, thus a curve, yet it passes through no rational point, as $\sqrt{2}\not\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I may be reading too much into this, but I think that the OP is asking weather the generic plane curve (if there is a way to formalise this notion) must have some rational points.